# Decomposing $\mathbf{\Pi}^1_1$ sets into closed sets

Tags: descriptive-set-theory, set-theory, lo.logic

It is well known that every $\mathbf{\Pi}^1_1$-set is a union of $\aleph_1$-many Borel sets. I wonder whether it can be improved under certain reasonable set theory axioms assumption.

For example, assuming  $ZFC+CH$, then it is trivially true that every set is a union of $\aleph_1$-many closed sets. But this seems heavily depends on $CH$ since  if $ZFC+\neg CH+MA$, then there is a lightface $\Pi^0_2$-set which cannot be a union of $\aleph_1$-many closed sets.

So my question is: is it consistent with $ZFC+\neg CH$ that every  $\mathbf{\Pi}^1_1$-set is a union of $\aleph_1$-many closed sets?

Comment: - Can you please give a reference for the above fact about $\Pi^0_2$ sets?
- If every lightface $\Pi^0_2$ is in boldface $\Pi^0_2$ (which is $\Pi^1_1$ then isn't this a counter-example to your question?

Comment: Just consider a $\Pi^0_2$, null, and comeager set, which cannot be a  union of $\aleph_1$-many closed sets under the assumption $ZFC+\neg CH+MA$. Here $MA$ really matters.

Comment: One approach to the question would be to consider what various cardinal invariants of the continuum must be like in order for your $\Pi^0_2$ set not to be a counterexample.  Then if these are known to be consistent you can analyze the specific models in which they are proved to hold.

Comment: If it's true for any uncountable Polish space then it's true for Cantor space (that's probably why you say in the comments below that the question is about Cantor space.)  

If it's true for Cantor space (even just for $\Pi^0_2$ sets) then the Baire space $\omega^\omega$ is the union of $\aleph_1$-many Meager sets, and is also the union of $\aleph_1$-many compact sets.  So you might want to look at iterated forcing extensions with these properties where CH fails.

Comment: Howard Becker and Randall Dougherty has a nice answer to the question: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870899918297?via%3Dihub

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every ${\bf\Pi}_1^1$ set is the union of $\aleph_1$ Borel sets, so we only have to make sure that every Borel set is the union of $\aleph_1$ closed sets.
But every Borel set is analytic and thus a continuous image of the Baire space $\omega^\omega$.
Now the Baire space is the union of $\mathfrak d$ (the dominating number) compact sets.  Continuous images of compact sets are again compact and hence every analytic set is the union of $\mathfrak d$ compact (and hence closed) sets.

It is well known that $\mathfrak d=\aleph_1$ is consistent with the failure of CH.
This happens for instance in the so called Sacks model.

---

Edit:  I forgot to mention that it was Paul Larson who turned my attention to this question.  Paul conjectured (or should I say, was convinced) that in the model obtained by forcing with a large countable support product of Sacks forcing over a model of CH every ${\bf\Pi}_1^1$ set is the union of $\aleph_1$ closed sets, 
which is true, since $\mathfrak d$ is $\aleph_1$ in that model.

Comment: Your answer is much better, however.

Comment: Dilip had a similar idea to Paul's. I think the direct method should work. A further question is whether every Borel set can be decomposed into $\aleph_1$ many disjoint closed sets?

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem of my teacher Steve Jackson which says that assuming $ZFC + AD^{L(\mathbb{R})}$ every projective set is $\aleph_{\omega}$-Borel. So in particular this holds for $\Pi^1_1$ sets. The proof uses the theory of descriptions and every other technical tool from descriptive set theory (homogeneous trees, scales,...). Also, with respect to $MA$ and $CH$, $AD$ can't decide them, so maybe that result might be what you're looking for, I'm not sure. You can find the result in this survey of Jackson ["A survey of Determinacy"](http://math.berkeley.edu/~steel/martin/jackson.martin.ps) somewhere in the end of the paper.

Comment: Actually $AD$ decides $CH$ (true), namely $M\models AD$ then $M\models CH$ (in the sense that every uncountable set of reals has size continuum). I believe that you wanted to say that $ZFC+AD^{L(\mathbb R)}$ cannot decide $CH$ in $V$.

Comment: Yes indeed, it's true.

Comment: It is a $ZFC$-theorem that every $\mathbf{\Pi}^1_1$-set is a union of $\aleph_1$-many Borel sets. The reason is (may be from a set theorist point of view) that it can be represented by an $\aleph_1$-Suslin set. Moreover it seems no way to improve the result by replacing Borel with closed via modifying the proof (the proof is by a so-called bar-induction, which use complement, union, and intersection transfinitely many times). Steve's result  essentially says every projective set can be represented by an $\aleph_{\omega}$-suslin set. 

Comment: Nice observation Yu. Concerning you original question, since you want $\Pi^1_1$ to be an $\aleph_1$ union of closed sets, is it possible to first start with your $\Pi^1_1$ set as a $\aleph_1$ union of Borel sets, then use that theorem which changes the topology to get a finer topology in which all these Borel sets are clopen and then say that the original $\Pi^1_1$ set is now an $\aleph_1$ union of clopen sets in the new topology? For this to happen, the space where all this takes place must be Polish.

Comment: It might work. So you want to solve the question by changing the topology? My question is only for Cantor space.

Comment: OK well, it seems like that's what should work. For any $\kappa$-Borel set one can transform it into a $\kappa$-clopen set just by modifying the topology by the "changing topologies theorem" which says that if $X$ is Polish (with topology $\tau$) and $A$ is a $\Sigma^0_{\alpha}$ set then we can always find a finer topology $\tau$' such that $A$ is clopen in $\tau$'. Also the new open sets are the old $\Sigma^0_{\alpha}$ sets. One nice consequence of the theorem is the perfect set property for Borel sets.

Comment: @alephomega: There are $\omega_1$ many Borel sets to consider, and their Borel ranks are generally unbounded in $\omega_1$, so how do you find a Polish topology that makes them *all* clopen?

Comment: @Trevor. The new topology need not be Polish. However if we have a countable collection of borel sets to start with then the new topology can be Polish and we can find a bound on the Borel rank. 

Comment: @alephomega: How does this apply to the question?  What is the countable collection of Borel sets you want to make clopen?

Comment: @Trevor: It was just a general fact about changing topologies, actually it does not really matter. The point is the new topology need not be Polish at all. But I might be completely misunderstanding the problem. If that is the case, then I'm sorry.

Comment: @alephomega: You can certainly find a finer topology containing whatever sets you want (e.g., the discrete topology) but if it's not Polish I don't see the point.  In fact, even it if is Polish I don't see how that answers the question as stated, which is how to take a $\Pi^1_1$ set (in some topology) and express it as a union of closed sets (in the same topology.)

Comment: My point was that every $\Sigma^1_2$ is a union of $\aleph_1$ many Borel sets, hence every $\Pi^1_1$ set is a union of $\aleph_1$ many Borel sets. If all these Borel sets can be transformed into closed sets then we'll be done: we would be able to write every $\Pi^1_1$ set as a union of $\aleph_1$ many closed sets. This is possible to do by changing topologies (the theorem I quoted above). This seems to take place in $ZFC$ + not-$CH$.

Comment: Does the new topology have any nice properties?  If not, why is this any better than just changing to the discrete topology?  This would also be a way to make all $\omega_1$ many of the Borel sets closed, but I don't think it would constitute an answer to the question.

Comment: Yes indeed you're right, if the topology doesn't have nice properties, that's just useless. Now looking back at my comments, I am completely wrong. I realize I don't know if the topology is Polish or not. What is true however is that if you have a Polish space X and a Borel set B in that space then you can find a new Polish topology in which B is clopen. So I indeed missed the point of your first question: how do we make them ALL clopen since we have $\aleph_1$ many of them and keep the topology Polish at the same time. Thanks for clarifying Trevor:) 